# why buttons not appear into widget in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

i need to create a simple widget into a function then call the function from the **inti** function any help for me?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label, Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


class LoopButton(BoxLayout):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoopButton , self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.build()
        


    def build(self):

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        btn1 = Button(text='Hello')
        btn2 = Button(text='World')
        layout.add_widget(btn1)
        layout.add_widget(btn2)
 
        return layout 

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoopButton()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

why my Buttons doesn't appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Buttons` are not appearing because you never add them to the `App` display.
Just replace:

```
return layout
```

with:

```
self.add_widget(layout)
```